# OperationalError at / attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: django, apache, sqlite, localhost

I configured Apache with Django. For that I had to move my django app to the server root directory. Now, I'm getting an error that my database is read only. I checked permissions and they didn't change after the move. Please help. It gives me this error:

```
OperationalError at /
attempt to write a readonly database
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem on a CentOS 7 system, where [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org) was running. If you have SELinux installed, you can check if it's enabled by running `sestatus` and possibly disable it (temporarily for testing) with `setenforce 0`.