# Can I safely delete Django's empty __init__ files?

Tags: python, django

I have many `__init__.py` files in my Django project and apps folder,

I think most were generated by Django when I initialised my project and its apps

I have seen in [How do I delete DB (sqlite3) in Django 1.9 to start from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150499/how-do-i-delete-db-sqlite3-in-django-1-9-to-start-from-scratch/42150639) that apparently we shouldn't delete the `__init__.py` file in the migration folders.

Can I delete the others, empty `__init__.py` files ? It s just that they kind of clutter the directory tree, so if they are useless I would rather remove them.

Edit : I just tried and deleted them and I didn t see any changes to the functionnalities of my website, everything worked fine. But as others pointed out they are definitely not useless so I ll leave them be.

Comment: Short answer, don't. Long answer 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the **__init__.py** file makes Python treat directories containing it as modules.

So by deleting that file Django doesn't treat it as a module and it will stop working.

So it is bad idea to delete those files.

Comment: I tried, deleted them all and saw no change whatsoever in the functionnalities of my website. But as you pointed out they are not useless so I ll leave them where they are.

Comment: Well, it depends on version of `Python` You're using. Newer `Python` versions do NOT require `__init__.py` file in order to recognize modules.