# Remove sqlite3 table from django project

Tags: python, django, sqlite

when I try to make migrations I am getting the following error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "main_todolist" already exists

This tablet is throwing an error and I dont want to use the table anyways, I am trying to get delete it or at least stop the error. Any suggestions? The more simple the solution the better, I am new to this.

Ive seen that I may need to access the dbshell however I also get the error " You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path". Ive tried appending \sqlite3 to the end of my path but to be honest I am not really sure how to append the path.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Ive seen that I may need to access the dbshell however I also get the error " You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path". Ive tried appending \sqlite3 to the end of my path but to be honest I am not really sure how to append the path.

This is because you did not install sqlite3 on your machine, you have to install it from sqlite website, then save it to a directory, and lastly put it in your machine environment path. That way your app can execute it.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "main_todolist" already exists.
>   This tablet is throwing an error and I dont want to use the table anyways, I am trying to get delete it or at least stop the error. Any suggestions? The more simple the solution the better, I am new to this.

For this one if you are just starting the project and has almost no data, I recommend resetting the database following the instruction of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42150639/12581324