Unable to do migrations in django

django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency userauths.0001_initial on database 'default'.


I have tried commenting "django.contrib.admin" and path("admin/", admin.site.urls),

I have tried python manage.py migrate userauths zero and then deleting all migration file except init file then python manage.py makemigrations userauths then after that I used python manage.py migrate


Still facing the same issue.

If you can reset the database tables too. The migration state in your database is inconsistent with the migration files present in your Django project.

Do you want help and don't show any code? It is a problem that this error occurs due to the signals

Hi! Could you share more information regarding what you'd like to accomplish?  Are you new to Django? If you're new, I recommend you start a new project following the steps of django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/ On the second page, you'll find the migration commands. Your database might be inconsistent. In this case, you can delete your DB like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42150639/7248916

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How many migration files do you have? If there's not too many, add them to your question to help us understand what is causing the problem.

Thank you so much for your support but i resolved the issue by deleting the sqlit then i re migarte and it was resolved
